Get theta based on known hypotenuse and adjacent
I'm finally trying to understand trigonometry and came across this random quiz question:

As you can see, I got this wrong. I'm having a hard time understanding why. Based on what I know we have:

A hypotenuse of 9
An adjacent of 5

So, we use cosine since we have the adjacent and hypotenuse.
cos(theta) = A/H

which would be
cos(theta) = 0.55

So, theta would be:
acos(0.55)

And to transform the radians in to degrees:
acos(0.55) * (180 / PI)

However, this gives me 56.63 which isn't close to any of the options there.

Is the triangle guaranteed to be a isosceles triangle? The posted picture looks like it could be one, but your question does not explicitly make such a statement.

My question didn't make that statement because theirs didn't. I didn't even realise it mattered but thanks to @Unmitigated I now know it does.

Use 5 as hypotenuse and "adjacent" as 4.5. Altitude of isosceles triangle bisects the base.

That's a brilliant idea! Are there any negatives to this approach?

This is not a programming question. You should ask on [math.se]

Not if you have inverse cosine handy.

You cannot consider 5 or 9 as the adjacent side since it is not a right angle triangle, but an isosceles triangle. Based on the markings, the unlabelled side also has length 5cm.
Given the lengths of 3 sides, we can find any angle with the Cosine Law. Here, we get:
5^2 = 9^5 + 5^2 - 2(9)(5)cos(x)
cos(x) = (9^2 + 5^2 - 5^2) / (2*9*5)
cos(x) = 9/10
x = arccos(0.9) ≈ 25.8°


Just when I thought I was getting the hang of this. Thanks for the information. I assumed we could just assume an adjacent. Looks like I have a bit further to go in my studies.

@Cjmarkham Happy to help.
